# How to achieve UITableview seperator 'above first row' without adding subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is there any way to achieve this without creating UIView and adding it as subview in UITablecell content view?[image: The line above first cell]

Comment: Add a section header.

Answer (score 2):

There is no public API in `UITableView` or `UITableViewCell` to do this. Adding a custom (Line-)`UIView` to the `UITableView`'s `headerView` should be the way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only that extra separator you can add it at the top of your `UITableView`. Otherwise, it isn't possible only with the default tableview separators to achieve the effect you want.